# How I can get current active Live streams list and filter them by description and location

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

JAVA/YouTube API v3

[I tried to do this through the developer's console](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus%22%2C%22broadcastStatus%22%3A%22active%22%2C%22broadcastType%22%3A%22all%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A25%7D)
and the JSON responce is:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
    "reason": "liveStreamingNotEnabled",
    "message": "The user is not enabled for live streaming.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://www.youtube.com/features"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The user is not enabled for live streaming."
 }
}
```

And PopUp that sais:

> This error may be due to using an insufficient credential type. Try using OAuth 2.0.

Same response from my code run:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException code: 403 : The user is not enabled for live streaming.
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.liveBroadcast",
    "message" : "The user is not enabled for live streaming.",
    "reason" : "liveStreamingNotEnabled",
    "extendedHelp" : "https://www.youtube.com/features"
  } ],
  "message" : "The user is not enabled for live streaming."
}
```

Ok. Thanks a lot to DaImTo!
I just don't need to use "youtube-livestreaming-api" for that!

Comment: I'm using auth authentification, maybe is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

as per the documentation [errors#liveBroadcasts_youtube.liveBroadcasts.transition](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/errors#liveBroadcasts_youtube.liveBroadcasts.transition)

## from comments actual usage of this api.

> The user that authorized the request is not enabled to stream live video on YouTube. The user needs to enable it find more information at youtube.com/features.
>
> The [YouTube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started) lets you create, update, and manage live events on YouTube.

Comment: Yes, I see. Sorry, maybe I need to concretize my question:
All that I need is to search for today's live streams(not streams os user that authorized, but all the streams, with search word). 
Maybe I need something else to use for that, some other function?

Comment: Thats not what this api is designed to do.  **The YouTube Live Streaming API lets you create, update, and manage live events on YouTube**